# Is `my_instance = MyClass(a, b).my_method(c)` an acceptable (Pythonic) pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conventions

I've been thinking about this for hours. I have a class which eventually requires (but will init without) some key attributes. Subclasses of this class require different attributes.

If it helps, this is a base MeshElement class for the Verts, Edges, and Faces in a half-edge data structure.

Often, I need to create an istance which is similar-but-not-identical-to another instance, so I have methods like the below `borrow_b` that copy attributes from one instance to another.

I couldn't come up with a `borrow_b` constructor that a) preserved / duplicated the type hinting from init and b) could be inherited by subclasses with different required attributes.

This is the sanest idea I've had, but it breaks the rule that "methods which modify an object return None."

```
class AB:

    def __init__(self, a: Optional[int] = None, b: Optional[int] = None):
        if a is not None:
            self.a = a
        if b is not None:
            self.b = b

    def borrow_b(self, other):
        self.b = other.b # already type hinted when other was initialized
        return self

# >>> one_two = AB(1, 2)
# >>> six_two = AB(6).borrow_b(one_two)
```

I realize of course that this could be broken into two lines:

```
six_two = AB(6)
six_two.borrow_b(one_two)
```

... and allow `borrow_b` to return None, but I like that the first looks more like a constructor, and I'm not convinced the first isn't "Pythonic."

Ears open for a better solution, of course.

FWIW,

```
six_two = AB(6, six_two.b)
```

... isn't a "workable" solution, because not all attributes I'd like to copy are "required." I usually want to copy some required arguments plus the kind of miscellaneous tags typically-but-not-necessarily attached to mesh elements (color, uv, hardness, etc.).

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the question here, but my first reaction is: a constructor is just another kind of callable. If your call site is not clear, requiring the use of keyword arguments in the callable is often a good way to make it clearer. More pragmatically: start with what you want the call site to look like, and then work backward to how the code needs to work to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Use class methods to implement alternate constructors. The purpose of an object is to hold state across multiple method calls or function boundaries; creating an object that is only used in one scope and immediately discarded suggests you just needed a function with appropriate parameters in the first place.

```
class AB:

    def __init__(self, a: Optional[int] = None, b: Optional[int] = None):
        if a is not None:
            self.a = a
        if b is not None:
            self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def borrow_b(cls, o1: AB, o2: AB):
        return cls(o1.a, o2.b)

one_two = AB(1, 2)
six = AB(6)
six_two = AB.borrow_b(one_two, six)
```

Yes, `six` appears to only be created to initialize `six_two`, but presumably it exists for some other reason already. You could otherwise define a class method that specifically takes one object and an arbitrary set of other arguments to override the "prototype". Something like

```
@classmethod
def make_from_prototype(cls, prototype, **kwargs):
    new_obj = cls(prototype.a, prototype.b)
    for attr, value in kwargs:
        setattr(new_obj, attr, value)
    return new_obj 

...

one_two = AB(1,2)
six_two = AB.make_from_prototype(one_two, b=6)
```

One drawback is that `make_from_prototype` bypasses type-hinting, since `**kwargs` can take an arbitrary set of keyword arguments. It would best
be used as a private class method that only serves as the base implementation for specialized class methods like `borrow_b`:

```
@classmethod
def _make_from_prototype(cls, prototype: AB, **kwargs):
    # Same definition as above

@classmethod
def borrow_b(cls, o1: AB, o2:AB):
    return cls._make_from_prototype(o1, b=o2.b)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, settattr from kwargs is (as far as I can tell) able to bypass type hinting. That's fine as long as a and b are explicit parameters in init, but subclasses may have different explicit parameters.

Comment: I strayed away from the desire for type hinting; I'll try to address that.

Comment: Thank you for having a look. The problem with initializing o1 inside a classmethod is that I'd have to explicate my "required" arguments somewhere in that classmethod. The only way o1.someattr will be recognized as a non-arbitrary kwarg (and be thus type hinted) is to pass through init (or a near copy of init). This would be acceptable if I didn't want to subclass AB with different inits.

Comment: How so? `o1` and `o2` have to be instances of `AB`, the arguments to create which are typed in `__init__`. Inside `borrow_b`, `o1.a` and `o2.b` must have the right type, because they came from objects initialized by `__init__`. (Assuming you are always using `__init__` to initialize them, and not setting attribute values manually after you create the instance, that is.)

Comment: You're right, I could use a classmethod to merge two existing instances, I could even do something like my_instance=ABconstructor(AB(a=6),one_two) I'm not sure if that's better or worse than my previous idea. I'll have a closer look at that one.